# What is a tainted binary package?

Tags: dpkg, packaging, deb

Using `dpkg` I created some `debian` packages containing self-written libraries that install without problems. But when I try to run `lintian` on one of them, I just get the following error:

```
warning: tainted binary package 'name of package', skipping
```

What does `tainted binary package` mean? I cannot find a description for this error anywhere.

Comment: At a guess it means something for which either the source is unavailable, or the license is not considered GPL-compatible (assuming a similar meaning to kernel taint).

Comment: A lot of official packages don't even have a license file. Not sure what you mean with no source available. But the Source field actually was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the control file, the `Source` field was set to the project path in our version control system. That path contained slashes of course, which is obviously not allowed. That error message sure could be a bit more precise.